# What determines what is returned/shown by irb?

Tags: ruby, irb

How does irb decide how to represent an object that is returned from a statement?

```
> "foo"
=> "foo"
> 2
=> 2
```

I thought it was the equivalent of `print object.inspect` or some such thing, but nothing I try returns the same output.

Comment: Calling `inspect` on both of your examples yields the output given. Perhaps provide an example where it's not true?

Comment: It simply prints the obj.inspect where obj is the return value of previous expression

Comment: Hm... you're right. When I asked the question I was experimenting with a `HTTParty::Response` in the context of pry, which uses pretty_inspect. I can't find where pretty_inspect is defined for `HTTParty::Response`... that will probably answer my confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `irb` implements a [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop). It pretty much does this behind scenes:

```
loop do
  '> '.display
  input = gets.chomp
  value = eval input
  puts " => #{value.inspect}"
end
```